# how to use mongoose find in my request for validation specific parameters

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

this is the product object in my DB -

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60983042001fcf4198ade76d"),
        "category" : 2,
        "gender" : "Men",
        "title" : "Blue Jeans",
        "description" : "fmwepfoqewmfer ferwf",
        "price" : 233,
        "image" : "fneif.jpg",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-05-09T18:56:02.557Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-05-09T18:56:02.557Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

and i want to validate products by category and gender together -

how to use the find() here?

```
 const products = await ProductDB.find()
```

how can i get only products with "category": something and "gender": something.
i want to use the request dynamically with the path: localhost:4200/gender/category
for displaying the products in my website

Comment: @turivishal no. i want to check what is the "category" and "gender" for validation i can't use - "category": "jeans", i want to check what is the category and gender dynamically

Comment: your question is not clear, can you edit your question and add more details.

Comment: @turivishal added

Comment: what you are getting in params? have you console request from your api. does api routes setup correctly? just post what is the issue we can't help in incomplete details.

Comment: @turivishal the question u sent helped. my bad.